# Why does it show "File not found" when I am trying to run a command from a docker file to find and remove specific logs?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a docker file which has below command.

```
#Kafka log cleanup for log files older than 7 days
RUN find /opt/kafka/logs -name "*.log.*" -type f -mtime -7 -exec rm {} \;
```

While executing it gives an error opt/kafka/logs not found. But I can access to that directory. Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where are the logfiles coming from that you want to delete? Are you creating old logs inside your image build? Is this directory part of a volume defined in your image (or a parent image)?

Comment: Those are application logs. No old logs are created inside the image build. Yes, the directory is a part of a volume defined in the image.

Comment: then the folder `/opt/kafka/logs` is not there in build stage

Answer (score 0):

Changing the contents of a directory defined with `VOLUME` in your Dockerfile using a `RUN` step will not work. The temporary container will be started with an anonymous volume and only changes to the container filesystem are saved to the image layer, not changes to the volume.

The `RUN` step, along with every other step in the Dockerfile, are used to build the image, and this image is the input to the container, it does not use your running containers or volumes for the build input, so it makes no sense to cleanup files that are not created as part of your image build.

If you do delete files created in your image build, you should make sure this is done within the same `RUN` step. Otherwise, files you delete are already written to an image layer, and are transferred and stored on disk, just not visible in containers based on the layer that includes the delete step.